# UWP: Get current CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10-universal

For UWP there are some changes in the CultureInfo according to the blog entry [CultureInfo changes in UWP](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2015/11/02/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp/). Can I take [GlobalizationPreferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences.languages.aspx) to get the `CultureInfo` correctly?

```
public CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo()
{
    return new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0].ToString());
}
```

Taken from [this example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/TodoLocalized/TodoLocalized.UWP/Localize.cs).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get the current culture of the OS?

Comment: I want to know the current language of the device (not region). Therefore I thought I could use `CultureInfo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I take GlobalizationPreferences to get the CultureInfo correctly?

Yes you can, I've tested your method, it works well by my side.

> I want to know the current language of the device (not region).

You can also use [Windows.Globalization.Language.CurrentInputMethodLanguageTag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.language.currentinputmethodlanguagetag.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the current enabled keyboard layout or Input.

Comment: Is `CurrentInputMethodLanguageTag` only available when a keyboard is present?

Comment: @testing, I think no, tested with mobile emulator and no present keyboard, it also works.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT actualy, that method does not return the correct CultureInfo in regards to the regional settings (which is what my article is about!)

Answer (score 5):

If what you require is the "correct" CultureInfo (the one taking into account the user/machine regional settings), then you should either use the information on that blog post, or even better, use the `GetLocaleInfoEx` Win32 API to retrive it.

I've written a [Part 2](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/05/03/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp-part-2/) of that article that includes a complete example of how to use this API.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this.